# how to keep the structure of the dictionary

Tags: python

Well i have the following dictionary:

```
 {'3d1011c0bade5f0a064f7daeef09e7acf900cfe8af09e025859b3426': ['mils news 02122002_0005.txt', 1] }
```

Where

```
 ['mils news 02122002_0005.txt', 1]
```

is a list. And now i have the following:

```
result_array = {k: db_array.get(k, 0)[1] + db_array.get(k, 0)[1] for k in set(db_array) | set(db_array)}
```

with this i want to sum the number that is in the list with another dictionary. So my question is how to keep the dictionary unchanged, coz i get the following:

```
{'3d1011c0bade5f0a064f7daeef09e7acf900cfe8af09e025859b3426': 2}
```

as a result.

Expected output:

```
{'3d1011c0bade5f0a064f7daeef09e7acf900cfe8af09e025859b3426': ['mils news 02122002_0005.txt', 2] }
```

According to the first answer of the user, tnx for the solution but i get the following for different keys:

```
db_array = {'a': ['mils news 02122002_0005.txt', 3]}
>>> result_array = {'b': ['mils news 02122002_0005.txt', 3]}
>>> result_array = {k: [db_array[k][0],db_array[k][1] + result_array.get(k, ['', 0])[1]] for k in set(db_array) | set(result_array)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
KeyError: 'b'
```

Comment: Are `db_array` and `db_array` two different dictionaries?

Comment: i put them twice for example... This is the original code:result_array = {k: db_array.get(k, 0) + result_array.get(k, 0) for k in set(db_array) | set(result_array)}

Comment: Well, the reuse of result_array is actually reasonably significant, I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the db_array[k][0] value in your dict generator expression:

```
dv = ['', 0]
result_array = {k: [
        db_array.get(k, result_array.get(k))[0],
        db_array.get(k, dv)[1] + result_array.get(k, dv)[1]
    ] for k in set(db_array) | set(result_array)}
```

Note that I updated the default value to `['', 0]` (and used a variable for that to increase readability) if the key is not already present in either dict. Note that for the first item in the list we fall back to result_array if the key was not present in db_array; the key is always present in at least one of the two dicts, this way you do not end up with empty string values.

If the key were not in the `result_array` dict, then your original default would cause problems, as you use an int `0` to then index as an array:

```
>>> result_array.get('foobar', 0)[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

(Updated to reflect your comment showing your original code).

Comment: well it also could happen that the number of keys(elements) in db_array are not the same with the elements of result_array.

Comment: `set(db_array) | set(result_array)` means take *all* keys from both dicts and combine them into one set, the union of the keys. Are you saying there could be keys in `result_array` that are not in db_array?

Comment: yes that's right, there could be a case that there will be no key in one of the array so there i have to combine it into one array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to put the `.get()` calls back in, with a more readable default. I also updated the way you retrieve the first item in your list to never be empty.